# How to reset value of Select and Input component in reactstrap on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, reactstrap

I have two components ***Select*** and ***Input*** from the **reactstrap** library. An item is selected from the dropdown and the Input is given, an add button is clicked to send the data to a table but the previous inputs stay in the fields after its added.
How do i reset the field back to the place holder once the button is clicked?
The select component looks like

```
         <Select
          name="Item"
          closeMenuOnSelect={true}
          components={animatedComponents}
          placeholder="Select Item"
          options={this.props.itemsOptions}
          onChange={(data) => this.handleOnDropDownSelect(data, "addItem")}
         />
```

and the input field:

```
        <Input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          placeholder="QTY"
          onChange={(e) => this.handleOnDropDownSelect(e, "quantity")}
          className="item-add-qty"
        />
```

Below is a part of *handleOnDropDownSelect()* function

```
else if (key === "addItem") {
  this.setState({
    itemToAdd: Object.assign({}, this.state.itemToAdd, { id: data.value }),
  });
} else if (key === "quantity") {
  this.setState({
    itemToAdd: Object.assign({}, this.state.itemToAdd, {
      quantity: parseInt(data.target.value),
    }),
  });
```

Comment: please add handleOnDropDownSelect() code

Comment: @AmareshSM done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When add button is clicked then **you to have clear the input and select tag element states to reset the fields**.

```
 this.setState(state => ({
      inputText: '',
      dropdown: ''
    }));
```

Just like the above code, set input(inputText) and select(dropdown) state value to `''`.

check the demo:

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      inputText: '',
      Item: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div >
      <h3 > TODO < /h3> 
      < TodoList items = {
        this.state.items
      }
      /> 
      <form onSubmit = {
        this.handleSubmit
      } >
      <label htmlFor = "new-todo" >
      </label> 
      
      < input name = "inputText"   id = "new-todo"   onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }     value = {this.state.inputText}/> 
     
     <button >  Add </button>

      < select name = "dropdown" onChange = {this.handleChange}
      value = {this.state.dropdown} >
      <option value = "" > please select < /option>
      <option value = "A" > Apple < /option>
      <option value = "B" > Banana < /option> 
      <option value = "C" > Cranberry < /option> 
      </select>
      </form> 
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.inputText, this.state.dropdown);
    let text = this.state.inputText + " " + this.state.dropdown;
    const newItem = {
      text: text,
    };

    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.concat(newItem),
      inputText: '',
      dropdown: ''
    }));

  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <ul > {
        this.props.items.map(item => ( <li > {item.text} < /li>))
      } </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  TodoApp / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the values for your Select & Input using **States/Refs** (depending on your requirement).

```js
const [dropDown, setDropdown] = useState("");
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

<Select ...options value={dropDown} />
<Input ...options value={input} />
```

And inside your **handleOnDropDownSelect**:

```js
const handleOnDropDownSelect = (val) => {
    setDropdown(val);
}
```

On **button** click, empty the state values:

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setDropdown("");
    setInput("");
}
```